# DBArtisan performance tweaks

Tags: database

DBArtisan 8.0.0 is egregiously slow on my machine (win XP 2 GB RAM).

There is no logging or tracing enabled. Yet, every time I try to type a query or switch between tabs, the tool hangs for several minutes.

Are there any tweaks I can use to improve performance of DBArtisan ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to DBArtisan 8.5 and have seen significant performance improvements over the previous version.